# How to call the function is_iq_swapped() in the class uhd::usrp::fe_connection_t?

Tags: c++, usrp, uhd

I am working with a USRP X310 equipped with two CBX (120 MHz) daughterboards. Also, I am learning the UHD driver by going through some C++ examples for the host PC. Based on my observations, in-phase and quadrature components are swapped for the Tx path. I realized there are functions namely is_iq_swapped() and is_i_inverted() in the class uhd::usrp::fe_connection_t. I would like to call them to make sure about the connection type for both Tx and Rx. But I am a beginner with C++ and UHD, and I could not find any examples on the Internet.

My other question is how I can swap it back if it is the case or how can I negate/invert the I/Q components via the UHD driver.

I ran the command uhd_usrp_probe on the terminal and it read "Connection type: QI" for the Tx paths and "Connection type: IQ" for the Rx path. But I would like to get output by calling those functions mentioned and modify the connection type myself.

I would be grateful if somebody could help me.